# How can i get a unique ID from file via node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, node.js-fs

I am trying to get a unique id/something from file so i can find the duplicate files.

I tried to use fs.statSync() but it doesnt seem to give a unique id.

Is there a way to get a unique something so i can compare the files?

Comment: The question is what exactly it is you wanna compare. If you want to compare file contents you could use [hashing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Comment: The unique ID of a file on Linux is the combination of file system ID and inode number. Get the FSID from `fs.statfsSync()` and the inode number from `fs.statSync()`.

Comment: @Mushroomator yes i want to compare file content like images or videos. Is there a npm module to hash the file using its file path?

Comment: @Barmar i am windows user, i dont know how to get the file system ID but i doesnt seem be ino is diffrent. i tried same images and ino is diffrent